# Improper Shadow on Duplicated Object

Tags: light

[image]

Hello, I made an object(left one) and I duplicated it and scaled by -1 in x direction(right one) to have it symmetric. Then i applied "Apply to Location, Scale&rotation and Origin to Geometry" But as in the picture, it is shaded improperly. What can problem be and how can I fix it ?

Comment: When scaling by -1 recalculate normals apart from applying scale. Or use Mirror modifier.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new at Blender so didn't know about normals. So i noticed it flipped my faces too when i applied to scale. Then i fliped normals and it fixed the problem :).